# How do I resolve this LVM issue in Ubuntu on a USB External Drive?

Tags: lvm, mount, unmount

I'll try to be brief and succinct.

I recently wiped my Ubuntu server and re-installed 20.04 on an older Proliant DL360.  This system had two seagate external USB drives attached to it which store a majority of the data that I need.

I'm trying to make heads or tails of the LVM setup, but my experience in this area is lacking.

#### Drive Situation

There are 9 physical disks on this system. 7 of them are in the built-in drive cage and 2 are external USB drives.

Two of the built-in drives are mirrored RAID 1.  The remaining 5 are RAID 0 (disaster waiting to happen.)  All are controlled by the hardware raid adapter, so Ubuntu sees them as two physical disks.

```
sda                               8:0    0 136.7G  0 disk             << --- RAID 1 Mirror
├─sda1                            8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                            8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                            8:3    0 135.7G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0            253:1    0 135.7G  0 lvm  /
sdb                               8:16   0 683.5G  0 disk             << --- RAID 0 (Eeek!)
└─vg0-lv--0                     253:0    0 683.5G  0 lvm  /home
sdc                               8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdc1                            8:33   0   3.7T  0 part 
  └─server1--vg-exodus          253:10   0   3.7T  0 lvm  /exodus     << --- External USB
sdd                               8:48   0   4.6T  0 disk 
├─sdd1                            8:49   0   200M  0 part 
└─sdd2                            8:50   0   4.6T  0 part 
  └─server1--vg-leviticus       253:2    0   4.6T  0 lvm  /leviticus  << --- External USB

Everything below this?  *Shrug*

sr0                              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
server1--vg-root-missing_0_0    253:3    0   135G  0 lvm  
└─server1--vg-root              253:4    0   135G  0 lvm  
server1--vg-swap_1-missing_0_0  253:5    0   976M  0 lvm  
└─server1--vg-swap_1            253:6    0   976M  0 lvm  
server1--vg-genesis-missing_0_0 253:7    0   410G  0 lvm  
└─server1--vg-genesis           253:8    0   410G  0 lvm  
server1--vg-exodus-missing_1_0  253:9    0    12M  0 lvm  
└─server1--vg-exodus            253:10   0   3.7T  0 lvm  /exodus
```

So, all in all Ubuntu sees 4 physical disks.

#### What's Happening

Every time I re-boot the system, the two external USB drives are not mounted.

#### What I do to access them

As I'm unsure how to resolve this permanently, I simply do the following every time I reboot the system:

`vgchange -ay --activationmode partial`

The reason I do this is because of the result I get from `vgchange -ay` which is this:

```
 WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 2M0sVx-6Kk3-Mc5V-ioNJ-O091-yncE-M6KpHy.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid JFIcey-3YHd-xhuh-b1JN-M8LB-ptdO-1zpoTf.
  WARNING: VG server1-vg is missing PV 2M0sVx-6Kk3-Mc5V-ioNJ-O091-yncE-M6KpHy (last written to [unknown]).
  WARNING: VG server1-vg is missing PV JFIcey-3YHd-xhuh-b1JN-M8LB-ptdO-1zpoTf (last written to [unknown]).
  Refusing activation of partial LV server1-vg/root.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
  Refusing activation of partial LV server1-vg/swap_1.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
  Refusing activation of partial LV server1-vg/genesis.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
  Refusing activation of partial LV server1-vg/exodus.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "server1-vg" now active
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg0" now active
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
```

The two missing PV's don't exist anymore.  They're gone.  So, I need to remove them so the VG will activate at boot, no?

What's the best course of action to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like you've wiped some of the data you intended to keep. It's time to give up and restore from backup.

Comment: There is no backup.  The only data I needed was on the two external USB drives.  The rest was on the 7 internal drives which was only config, etc.  I wiped it, started from scratch, and now have an incomplete old VG with PV's that have changed intentionally.

Comment: No Backup? Then close your question anf start from scratch, that what Michael will tell you...

Comment: Not sure why I would need a backup of something I don't need anymore.  The only data I care about is safe and sound on the external usb drives.  I just need to get those two PV's into the new VG on the system, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your physical volume is gone then there is no chance to recover your VG and LV and it's time to start from fresh.

Comment: I'm not interested in recovering the VG or LV.  The new install has a new VG and LV, but it's recognizing the two external USB drives as part of the old VG with the old LV.  If I could simply move them into the new VG it would be satisfactory.  I just don't know if that's possible.  If it's not, then clearly I'll need to move all of the data from the drive, wipe the drive, add it to the new VG and move the data back on to it...more work than I would imagine is necessary.